# Is there an equivalent to Chrome developer tools (ctrl+shift+I) for Safari running on a mobile device

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, mobile-safari

(I have Googled a lot but either I do not understand the info or ...?)

So on the desktop I can debug my site using Chrome Dev. Tools. All good.

But a small part of my site does not run correctly on my new iPad Pro with iOS 10 (it seems to be OK with iOS 9, 8)

Can someone please point me down the right path.

Thanks

Comment: [Remote debugging iOS Safari on OS X, Windows and Linux](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/)?

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm.Sorry I forgot to mention I want to debug on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If the suggestion from @w0xxOm is no good for you on Windows, [Browserstack](http://browserstack.com) is a great alternative.

Comment: Thanks but I subscribe to BrowerStack. No developer tools for iPad iOS greater than 8, only have developer tools for Real Devices and iOS 7 and 8. (as at Jul 9, 2017)